# Execute PostgreSQL anon block from java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Hi I have PostgreSQL a anonymous block, e.g., DATA is a String variable in java(in which my anon block)

```
DO $$DECLARE  new_issue  text;
BEGIN
   new_issue := ?; 
   UPDATE FORM9902 SET HAS_ISSUE = 'Y',ISSUE_DESC = ISSUE_DESC || new_issue
   WHERE FORM990_ID = ?;
 END $$;
```

I am executing the above block as

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(DATA);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "hai");
preparedStatement.setLong(2, new Long(0));

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

But it is throwing exception as follows.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:63)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:126)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.bindString(PgPreparedStatement.java:1096)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:369)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:353)
at sample.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:20)
```

Could anyone help me on this or point me to the correct resource where i can correct my self.

Answer (score 7):

The PostgreSQL protocol does not provide ways to bind parameters to non-planned statements (or to non-query-parameter points).  This means that you cannot parameterize such statements.  In other words, you cannot bind parameters in such do block.

The stack trace shows that this is your problem.  You will need to sanitize parameters yourself and do string interpolation.

A better approach is to have a function where you can pass these in as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
String updsql = " UPDATE FORM9902 SET HAS_ISSUE = 'Y', ISSUE_DESC = ISSUE_DESC || ? WHERE FORM990_ID = ? ";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updsql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "hai");
preparedStatement.setLong(2, 0L);

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```