# Mybatis Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

```
<update id="export_orders_far_region">
    DO $$
    DECLARE
        ids varchar(15)[];
        export_in_progress boolean;
    BEGIN
    export_in_progress := (select case when EXISTS (select 1 from clt$task_far_export
    <if test="REGION != null"> where REGION = #{REGION}</if>
    ) then true else false end);

    IF export_in_progress = false THEN
    select ACT_ID into ids from clt$task_far
    <if test="REGION != null"> where REGION = #{REGION}</if>
    ;

            insert into clt$task_far_export (REGION, COLLECTION_CENTER, ACT_ID, FAZ_SZ)
            (select REGION, COLLECTION_CENTER, ACT_ID, FAZ_SZ from clt$task_far where ACT_ID like ANY(ids));

            delete from clt$task_far where ACT_ID like ANY(ids);
        END IF;
    END;
    $$
</update>
```

"text":"Cannot process region","envType":"K8S","podName":"mc-app-5df74b88f-6gm4v","localTime":"2022-07-13T21:35:00.075Z","threadName":"Thread-10 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)","projectCode":"CLTM","stack":" org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: \n### Error updating database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='REGION', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.\n### The error may involve defaultParameterMap\n### The error occurred while setting parameters\n### SQL: DO $$         DECLARE             ids varchar(15)[];             export_in_progress boolean;         BEGIN         export_in_progress := (select case when EXISTS (select 1 from clt$task_far_export           where REGION = ?          ) then true else false end);          IF export_in_progress = false THEN         select ACT_ID into ids from clt$task_far           where REGION = ?          ;                  insert into clt$task_far_export (REGION, COLLECTION_CENTER, ACT_ID, FAZ_SZ)                 (select REGION, COLLECTION_CENTER, ACT_ID, FAZ_SZ from clt$task_far where ACT_ID like ANY(ids));                  delete from clt$task_far where ACT_ID like ANY(ids);             END IF;         END;         $$\n### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='REGION', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:172)\n\tat com.business.integration.flows.out.ExportActivitiesFar.processRegion(ExportActivitiesFar.java:73)\n\tat com.business.integration.flows.AbstractOutFlow.executeForRegion(AbstractOutFlow.java:71)\n\tat com.business.integration.flows.AbstractOutFlow.execute(AbstractOutFlow.java:47)\n\tat com.integration.consumer.ExportTaskConsumer.onMessage(ExportTaskConsumer.java:44)\n\tat sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor197.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)\n\tat org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)\n\tat org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:253)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:332)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:238)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)\n\tat org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)\n\tat org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:57)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:243)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)\n\tat org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)\n\tat org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)\n\tat com.integration.consumer.ExportTaskConsumer$$$view52.onMessage(Unknown Source)\n\tat sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor197.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:139)\n\tat org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73)\n\tat com.integration.consumer.ExportTaskConsumer$$$endpoint2.onMessage(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQMessageHandler.onMessage(ActiveMQMessageHandler.java:303)\n\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1001)\n\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:49)\n\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1124)\n\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:122)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\nCaused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='REGION', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:89)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.parameterize(PreparedStatementHandler.java:85)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.parameterize(RoutingStatementHandler.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doUpdate(BatchExecutor.java:69)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:75)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:170)\n\t... 78 more\nCaused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:87)\n\t... 84 more\nCaused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.type.UnknownTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(UnknownTypeHandler.java:45)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:53)\n\t... 85 more\nCaused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:70)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:133)\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.bindString(PgPreparedStatement.java:1058)\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:364)\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:350)\n\tat org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.setString(CachedPreparedStatement.java:201)\n\tat org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setString(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:691)\n\tat sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor196.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:67)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy320.setString(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.type.StringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(StringTypeHandler.java:31)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.type.StringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(StringTypeHandler.java:26)\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:53)\n\t... 87 more\n","eventId":"458f4465-b70f-43f5-87aa-0cc963b829e7","risCode":"839"

Why?Can you give me some advice to solve this problem?Thanks.

Comment: Please enable DEBUG level [logging](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html) and add the output (SQL and parameters) to the question.

Comment: The driver does not support it, it seems. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721091/1261766).

Comment: BTW, it is possible to call a FUNCTION/PROCEDURE. Here is an executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-63701701).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).